# Can't save changes when I try to rename document title in a Linkedin post

Tags: linkedin-api

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyn5o.png)

Linkedin's help page tells me the following:

> You can edit the title and description of your document, but you can’t change or edit the document in the post. You can always delete the post entirely and create a new post with the updated document.

Is there another way for Linkedin to update the document title in a post? Maybe through an API request?

Linkedin's help page: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a523054